# wp-cli: Error establishing a database connection: undefined constant DB_USER

Tags: database, wp-cli

Bringing this over from the wp-cli github page. I've been searching here, the docs, and the webs for several hours. Currently hosting with Blue Host and they are using version 1.2.0 :( I can't seem to update.
I have 3 wp pages that work "perfectly" fine, but one other just won't connect to the db.

I can log in to db with same credentials as wp-config.php, cleaned up db, still no luck.

Any thoughts on this? Trying to ultimately maintain these pages better through wp-cli. Thanks

wp core version: returns fine.

```
wp config path --debug
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.267s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.268s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /home/public_html/domain/ (0.269s)
Debug (bootstrap): Begin WordPress load (0.269s)
Debug (bootstrap): wp-config.php path: /home/public_html/domain/wp-config.php (0.269s)
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in /home/public_html/domain/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASSWORD - assumed 'DB_PASSWORD' in /home/public_html/domain/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' in /home/public_html/domain/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in /home/public_html/domain/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
Notice: Undefined variable: table_prefix in /home/public_html/domain/wp-settings.php on line 109
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `DB_HOST`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
```

wp-config.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'dbuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wps_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300 );
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5 );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 7 );
define( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 120 );
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was the wp-config.php

Though not sure what. I copied the content of wp-config-sample.php while keeping the same db credentials and it started working. I then reverted the changes and it is still working...

Only differences were:

Initially, when replacing the file, the Salts were not set.

And hese lines...

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300 );
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5 );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 7 );
define( 'WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT', 120 );
```

If it comes back I'll look at the 4 defines... Hope this helps somebody, I was ripping my hairs out of my head!!